# Non sequential Pagination PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, navigation, pagination

I am currently trying to set up some sort of pagination in PHP but not having much luck. All of the tutorials I find are sequential ones done by ID so +1 or -1 but in my situation that will not work.

I am trying to display different delivery addresses linked to customers. So far I have connected to MySQL, ran the query to get what information I need and put it into an array, This array now stores an ID and a customer ID. Each ID is different because they have been added at different times. For example one is 379 in the same Customer ID is also 707, so I cannot just +1.

I hope these details can help.. Is there any way of setting it up so the links generated will only have those IDs ? So if a user chooses say, Customer ID 14, then they can see only the delivery addresses linked to 14, which might be delivery address 300 and 500?

Thank you so much for reading if you get this far, I have no idea and I have nearly pulled all of my hair out!

Comment: Seems like the issue isn't related to your pagination script but rather the query of the rows you're trying to display.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I'm not sure what you are trying to say? In the respect of what I need to do?

Comment: So for example: you're doing SELECT * FROM sometable LIMIT 0,10; and all you need to add is WHERE customer_id = 14 and that'll show you all results for this particular customer. I assume you're talking about pagination links (+1/-1) so ?page=2 (2 doesn't mean it has ID of 2, it's the second page which resulted in a generated query of LIMIT $page(in this case it's one so it should be 2)*$limitOfRowsPerPage, $limitOfRowsPerPage

Comment: you're reading the wrong tutorials, or reading them wrong, then. pagination has to do with offsets within a result set, not "ids". e.g. you're on page 10, displaying 20 records/page, you'd do `select ... limit 100,20` to get page ten. page 9 is `limit 80,20`, page 11 is `limit 120,10`. nowhere do you ever have to directly deal with record IDs. just offsets.

Comment: @MarcB good job, I wasn't sure how to explain it myself :)

Comment: Also could we see the code you've got so far?

Comment: @Ignas You are correct, my code is very scattered at the moment trying different snippets, I dont have something fully to show you as I dont know what exactly I'm doing. Could you expand on the $page* $limitOfRowsPerPage please?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you're getting the IDs of your customer addresses and putting that number as the index value in your array.

You wish to interate through your array but you can't iterate + 1 because of the numbers.

Use `foreach()` on the array. E.g.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key : $value <br />";
}
```

`$key` will be the ID of the address that you set. You can manipulate this to create links only to those addresses. I hope I've understood what you're asking for.

Comment: I don't think it's what he wants. He's not asking about the iteration of the array but more likely about the actual selection of data (MySQL related). Also he could loop through the data using a for loop, because the result set being returned is most likely to be numerically indexed.

Comment: @monkeymatrix , Hi, thanks for your answer but how would I implement this code? for example what I have seen so far is generating the html link and using something like $key + 1 ? Which doesnt seem to be working?

Comment: If your result set is put in `$array`, you can loop through it as above to create HTML links. So do something like `echo "<a href="yourpage.php?addressID=$key">Address ID: $key</a>"`